# XAML Binding Properties

Tags: xaml, binding, properties

Hi,
Can someone point me to some sort of documentation that has a complete list of the properties and their value types that Binding class offers.

```
<Image Source={Binding ......}/>
```

Basically a list of all the properties that go after the **Binding** keyword.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Binding markup extension - WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413.aspx)

[Binding markup extension - Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189022(VS.95).aspx)