# Create form bound to object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XAML Binding Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760404/xaml-binding-properties)

I was wondering how in WPF do you bind an object to a form, etc have all its properties linked to fields on the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at MVVM pattern.
This is a very good video I found very helpful to understand the topic for myself
[MVVM Pattern explained](http://www.lab49.com/files/videos/Jason%20Dolinger%20MVVM.wmv)

Comment: Using MVVM is a good idea, but it would be better for @Alex to get the basic databinding concepts first.

Comment: The link is gone: Page not found

Answer (score 2):

[Bing search : xaml + binding](http://www.bing.com/search?q=xaml%20binding&go=)

But seriously http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748857.aspx this is a good one from msdn [wpf binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) section

Answer (score 2):

You need to go and read some tutorials on [DataBinding](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wpf%20databinding%20form%20tutorial).